# php reading value from an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, object

I have an array and I am trying to access the value for message. I think it is throwing me off because it is an array of objects within an object. Below is what I have tried and the data structure.

Code:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {

         echo "$value[0]->message"; 
}
```

Array:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [message] => 12345
                    [unit] => test
                    [createdAt] => 2013-01-21T14:57:26.613Z
                    [updatedAt] => 2013-01-21T14:57:26.613Z
                    [objectId] => 0uiYuJcRYY
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove quotes

```
foreach ($result as $value) {

         echo $value[0]->message; 
}
```

Comment: If their were multiple objects in the list, how would I access each of them? Would it be another foreach statement within the foreach statement?

Comment: yes, if $value from your loop contained another array of objects then to print them all you would need to run another loop on those

Comment: @JonErickson You are most welcome. I must appreciate that you were almost there yourself, so this is almost your own answer. It was just a matter of quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two pobable mistakes.

1 - Probable the variable are $results and not $result
2 - If you are using foreach, you don't need the [0], because this is the variable $value now.

try

```
foreach ($results as $value) {
    echo $value->message; 
}
```